# Ionic Android app has no internet access on signed release apk but debug works fine

Tags: android, cordova, ssl, nginx, ionic-framework

My app works fine in the debug apk, but as soon as I build and sign a release version, my app has no internet access and no requests work. All requests are made over https.

My server uses https on nginx to reverse proxy requests to a node.js server. I looked at other issues and they say it has something to do with interimediate ssl certificate problems on the server. I'm rather new to configuring ssl and I'm not sure what that means or how to fix it, but the server works fine normally over https.

Comment: I've the same issue. Have you solved this problem?

Comment: @CBastianelli Yes I did, check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I got this fixed a long time ago. I contacted Comodo customer support and they gave me the correct root and intermediate certs to use. I guess there's something that blocks ssl certificates that don't have a full keychain back to the CA.

So anyone else having this issue, just contact your CA and ask them for the proper intermediate and/or root certificates.

Comment: I've fixed it too, my cert had 2 certificates instead of one.